# Searching for (any) strings in another string separated by non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split, text-parsing, mathjs

How can I extract words (which can be anything) out of a string which are separated by non-alphabetic characters (digits or symbols) and save the result in an array.

For example if I parsed the following I would like to have the name of the three fruits in an array.

```
var input str = '= ((1 * bananas ^ 5) - oranges / mangos)'  // to get [bananas, oranges, mangos]
```

The practical application of this is that, I would like to extract variable names from a mathematical formula, after which I can assign values to them (which I'd get from some object or array)

Comment: Why not "x" and "y"?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it's getting late here. Yes I meant all variables. See updates above.

Comment: `1` and `5` are alphanumeric, why aren't they in the results?

Comment: that should have been phrased 'alphabetic. I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `[a-z]+`:

```
'= ((1 * bananas ^ 5) - oranges / mangos)'.match(/[a-z]+/ig)
```